# GWcode Categories and class_current is not added

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

My code for GWcode Categories add-on looks like:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="4" cat_url_title="{segment_2}" last_only="yes" class="list-plain" class_current="current_category"}
<a href="{path="{segment_1}/{complete_path}"}">{cat_name}</a>
/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Based on Nick suggestion I have used GWcode CatMenu add-on

```
{exp:gwcode_catmenu group_id="4" cat_url_title="{segment_2}" min_depth="2" class="list-plain"}
<a href="{path="{segment_1}/{complete_path}"}"
{if active} class="current"{/if}>
{cat_name}
</a>
{/exp:gwcode_catmenu}
```

but I have no clue why on current category class is not added.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wasn't able to get GW CatMenu output categories in a way I want, I have decided to go back to GW Categories and use logic below to indicate active/current category:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="4" cat_url_title="{segment_2}" last_only="yes" class="list-plain"}
{if "{segment_3}"=="{cat_url_title}"}{cat_name}
{if:else}
<a href="{path="{segment_1}/{complete_path}"}">{cat_name}</a>
{/if}
{exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the [GW CatMenu](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-catmenu/documentation) add-on; class_current isn't listed in the docs for GW Categories.

Comment: I have try to use that add-on but with that code `{exp:gwcode_catmenu group_id="4" cat_url_title="{segment_2}" depth_open="2" class="list-plain"}` I'm getting all categories from group 4 instead only child categories whatever is under parent category based on URL.

Comment: Please check OP for edits.